# Didn't find class "androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout"

Tags: android, androidx

After migrating to Androidx packages using Android Studio menu option Refactor -> Refactor to Androidx...

my build.gradle looks like

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

During run the app, I run into this:

```
Didn't find class "androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout"
```

It seems the migration tool has same issues

Comment: Where? When? What does your gradle config look like?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I was able to solve it by 
Just replace

```
androidx.core.widget.DrawerLayout
```

with

```
androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
```

in every place where it appears.

Comment: Bingo. I was tearing my hair out over this. Thank you. Why, why even do this to people, Google?

Comment: I though the whole point of androidx was to unify things ! Go figure.