# Android Studio says "androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout" was not found in the project or libraries, even though I already add it in the gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8LGg.png)

Also below is the code text from the same snippet that has been attached.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
```

Comment: does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53635207/10409567

Comment: It doesn't work too.....The error only shows on this project, but when I create new project, it seems fine

Comment: I'm currently using AppCompat......Relative Layout...does this thing matter on my problem??

Comment: have you tried the good old invalidate cache and restart

Comment: did you check ending tag of `drawer layout` it must close and this should be a root layout

Comment: Did you click on ->sync after adding the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing any of these methods:

- Close your android project by going to File -> Close Project. And then import it again
- If above option doesn't works for you then Go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

If neither of them work the remove the dependency and add it again and tell me the build output when gradle sync finishes

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that your studio cache is corrupted;

So

- close your all project first; then
- open your studio path in your `C:\` Drive; for eg. it should like `C:\Users\hp(Your_User_Name)\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches`...  Delete this `caches` folder.

Now start your project again, issue will gone now.

Hope this may help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work for you, but it did for me:

I just launched the app with `Ctrl` + `F5` despite the problem. Once it executes successfully, the problem disappears.

Don't comment-out the `DrawerLayout`! Keep its body empty if needed, and just start the app.